# Connecting Wouxun KG-699E to computer sound card audio input/output

Tags: diy, ht

I have a Wouxun KG-699E and I am trying to connect it to audio connectors in a PC. Right now, I have connected it by this [schematic](http://www.qsl.net/g4wpw/th78a.jpg) (it uses Kenwood-type of headset connector) where instead of external Speaker and external MIC is 3,5mm TRS jacks (only Tip and Sleeve connected). The one from ext. speaker leads to MIC hole in the external soundcard and the one from ext.MIC leads to the speaker hole in the external soundcard.

I can listen to the signal received by the Wouxun, but when I engage PTT connection it starts to transmit "empty" signal (no voice, just like you hold PTT and don't say anything). Even though I know that there is signal going from soundcard (I have a jack splitter and headphones).

There is probably something I missed in the wiring, but I can't figure out what it is. Or, can I use the USB programming cable directly to broadcast/listen to frequency?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you've accidentally shorted out the speaker to ground? Not all radios use mono jacks, and you might be connecting something when you use a stereo jack that you don't intend.

Here's what Singalink recommends:
http://www.tigertronics.com/sl_wireht_sep.htm

In particular, the PTT on the ring of the 2.5mm plug might be causing you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a DIY solution but I thought I would comment since you are looking for a USB direct to audio. You may want to consider the Tigertronics SingaLink USB, it has a cable to support Kenwood HTs and supports audio sense feature for PTT. I successfully got this working with a Raspberry PI and a Kenwood TH-F6A so I needed the sound card interface. Unfortunately, this solution costs more than the radio.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try incresing the output volume on the computer?  Play with the audio controls and see if that changes anything.  You may want to keep the headset on the desk for this until you see if it works and at what sound level.